# Stuck with mootools script. Image autochange

Tags: javascript, mootools

```
<div id="contentimage">
    <img src="1.jpg" class="activeimage" />
    <img src="2.jpg" style="opacity: 0;" />
    <img src="3.jpg" class="last" style="opacity: 0;" />
</div>

<script>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    var fx = function() {

    var activeimage = $$('img.activeimage');

        if(!activeimage.hasClass('last')) {

            var next = activeimage.getNext('img');

            activeimage.toggleClass('activeimage');
            next.toggleClass('activeimage');

            activeimage.morph({'opacity':'0'});
            next.morph({'opacity':'1'});

        } else {

            var next = $('contentimage').getFirst('img');

            activeimage.toggleClass('activeimage');
            next.toggleClass('activeimage');

            activeimage.morph({'opacity':'0'});
            next.morph({'opacity':'1'});

        }

    }

    fx.periodical(3000);

});
</script>
```

I just can't understand why this :

```
if(!activeimage.hasClass('last'))
```

always returns false ? I tried to check it with "alert", and it was all good, but when it comes to this line - it goes not like I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var activeimage = document.getElement('img.activeimage');
```

Otherwise `$$` will get a `family` and you cannot apply `.hasClass()` like that.

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DNREc/)** (check console after some seconds)